# private modifier in php doesn' work like expected

Tags: php, private, access-modifiers

i have this class

```
class Product {
    public $name;
    private $price2;
    protected $number;

function getNmae() {
    return $this->name;
}

function getPrice() {
    return $this->price2;
}

function getNumber() {
    return $this->number;
}
}
```

and here I can use private price without any problem?

```
<?php
include 'oop_test.php';

class Banana extends Product {
   
   
}


$ba = new Banana();
echo $ba->price2 = 2000;

?>
```

the result like this:
[image]

I cannot understand how could I assign value to private variable ?

Comment: Fun fact: `$p = new Product(); $p->price2 = 2000;` fails as expected.

Comment: but why it does work with derived class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've created a property on-the-fly in this case. A reduced sample shows this:

```php
<?php
class Product {
    private $price2;

    function getPrice() {
        return $this->price2;
    }
}

class Banana extends Product {}


$ba = new Banana();
$ba->price2 = 2000;

echo 'On the fly property: ' . $ba->price2;
echo 'Private property: ' . $ba->getPrice();
```

That code prints `2000` for the property `price2`, but nothing is returned from `getPrice` - so you haven't **really** written the property `price2` on the `Product` class, but created a new one within the `Banana` class.

The "original" property from the `Product` class is not involved here, as it is a private property and thus not available in the `Banana` class after all.

Comment: thanks, but my question still, why?

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? The `Banana` class does not have a `price2` property yet, so setting it is fine. This could be different with a `protected` property, as this would be visible to `Banana` too

Answer (score 2):

Actually the display of 2000 does not mean that the parent class value is set.

Your statement only creates a new variable for the class itself, not for the parent class because the price2 is not declared as protected / public.

It explains why the system does not throw an error in your case

Recap:

- `public` scope to make that property/method available from anywhere, other classes and instances of the object.
- `private` scope when you want your property/method to be visible in its own class only.
- `protected` scope when you want to make your property/method visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class

Try create a method (say setPrice) to set the price2 in the parent class if you need to set a value for this private variable

```
<?php
class Product {
   private $price2;

   function setPrice($a) {
     $this->price2 = $a;
   }

   function getPrice() {
   return $this->price2;
   }
}

class Banana extends Product {
   }


$ba = new Banana();

//$ba->price2 = 2000; 

/*The above will not throw an error even executed 
because it is creating a property within 
the banana class*/

$ba->setPrice(2001);

echo $ba->getPrice();

/*The above is for setting / getting 
the price2 private variable 
in the parent class-just for illustration*/

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. OP is wondering why their code _works_. You seem to explain why it _doesn't_.

Comment: The OP code does not work actually. The display of 2000 does not mean the value is set, but may be let me show more details to him....

Comment: Regardless of set or not - already _accessing_ the property should fail (as it does for an instance of `Product`), shouldn't it?

Comment: I have amended my answer. See whether it is clear

Answer (score 0):

FYI from PHP 8.2 onward the OP code generates a 'deprecated' message, alerting this confusing behavior:

```
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property Banana::$price2 is deprecated
```

To restate the explanations: the OP code works because in PHP before 8.2 was OK to create properties on the fly:

```php
<?php
class Banana {}

$b = new Banana();
$b->price = 2000; // At this point, PHP <8.2 creates a public property `price` on the object $b, and assigns it a value
echo $b->price; // The newly created public property works as usual
```

In your code, you explicit declared a *private*  property on a parent class. Private properties are only private for the class where they're were explicit declared. So this obviously won't work:

```php
<?php
class Product
{
    private $price;
}

$b = new Product();
$b->price = 2000; // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Product::$price
```

But when you extended `Product`, the child class won't have that property defined, because is *private* to the parent `Product`:

```php
class Product
{
    private $price;
}

class Banana extends Product {}

$b = new Banana();
$b->price = 2000; // Again, this works because PHP creates a new public property `price` on object `$b`
```

If you want to inherit the "private" property from parent to child, you should declare it `protected`:

```
<?php
class Product
{
    protected $price; // Now all its children will inherit this "private" property
}

class Banana extends Product {
}

$b = new Banana();
$b->price = 2000; // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Banana::$price
```

And a bit more: If nowadays you really *really* want to create dynamic properties, you should add the attribute `#[AllowDynamicProperties]` to the class, so PHP won't emit the deprecation message.

```
<?php
#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class Banana {}

$b = new Banana();
$b->price = 2000; // Now it's OK
```